# Wifi randomly drops out while still connected to network?

Tags: wireless

I'm running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 wily on my macbook pro 2009, I've noticed that sometimes my wifi drops out randomly while it still shows it's connected. Only way to fix this as far as i've found is to turn the wifi off and back on. Is there any way to solve this problem permanently?

Thanks in advance!